# MIN() against partition in Group in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want MIN() against the partition in SQL server

```
MY CODE

DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO INT,DATA VARCHAR(5),DATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (1,'A','2015-11-25 18:37:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (2,'A','2015-11-25 18:36:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (3,'A','2015-11-25 18:35:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (4,'B','2015-11-25 18:34:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (5,'B','2015-11-25 18:33:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (6,'B','2015-11-25 18:32:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (7,'B','2015-11-25 18:31:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (8,'B','2015-11-25 18:30:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (9,'A','2015-11-25 18:27:59.120')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DATE) VALUES (10,'B','2015-11-25 18:26:59.120')

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS ROW_NUM,
    DATA,
    MAX(DATE) AS MAX_DATE   ,
     MIN(DATE) AS MIN_DATE
FROM
    #TEMP_TABLE
GROUP BY 
    DATA
```

**MY OUTPUT**

[image]

**EXPECTED DATA**
[image: expected output]

I want min Date as the group of the record as min date & max date.
Means lets say first group of records in the above data are

```
data time
A    5:00
A    4:00
A    3:00
B    2:00
A    1:00
```

then I want to return output as

```
data    max  min
a      5:00  3:00
```

Comment: The images don't explain anything. And they don't match your sample below. Better remove them completely and enhance your sample data instead. Am I right to assume, you consider your sample data to be three groups: A 5:00/3:00, B 2:00/2:00, A 1:00/1:00? But you only want to show the *latest* group, which is A 5:00/3:00? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    MAX(DATA) AS DATA,
    MAX([DATE]) AS MAX_DATE,
    MIN([DATE]) AS MIN_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT *, val = 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)
    FROM #TEMP_TABLE
) t
GROUP BY val
```

output -

```
DATA  MAX_DATE                MIN_DATE
----- ----------------------- -----------------------
A     2015-11-25 15:53:12.940 2015-11-25 15:51:12.940
B     2015-11-25 15:50:12.940 2015-11-25 15:48:12.943
C     2015-11-25 15:47:12.943 2015-11-25 15:46:12.943
A     2015-11-25 15:43:12.943 2015-11-25 15:43:12.943
D     2015-11-25 15:45:12.943 2015-11-25 15:42:12.943
```

update -

```
SELECT *,
    row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC),
    row_id_by_data = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY [DATE] DESC),
    group_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)
FROM #TEMP_TABLE
```

result -

[image]

Comment: whatever you have posted in the answer is absolutely perfect. But i did not understood what these lines are doing val = 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)
Please can you help me to understand teh concept

Comment: please check the updated answer and info from this post - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are looking for something like what I have here. (I changed the table declaration because I didn't want it hanging around after I tested this)

```
DECLARE @TEMP_TABLE TABLE (SR_NO INT,DATA VARCHAR(5),DT DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (1,'A',(DATEADD(MINUTE,11,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (2,'A',(DATEADD(MINUTE,10,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (3,'A',(DATEADD(MINUTE,9,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (4,'B',(DATEADD(MINUTE,8,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (5,'B',(DATEADD(MINUTE,7,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (6,'B',(DATEADD(MINUTE,6,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (7,'C',(DATEADD(MINUTE,5,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (8,'C',(DATEADD(MINUTE,4,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (9,'D',(DATEADD(MINUTE,3,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (10,'D',(DATEADD(MINUTE,2,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (1,'A',(DATEADD(MINUTE,1,GETDATE())))
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE (SR_NO,DATA,DT) VALUES (1,'B',GETDATE())

SELECT DATA, MAX(DT) as MaxDate, MIN(DT) as MinDate
FROM @TEMP_TABLE
GROUP BY DATA
```

Comment: you have just copy & pasted my code i don' see that you have change any of the code

Comment: Sorry. I copied the top section and played with it to get an answer, then didn't see it was the same as yours. Some days, my brain just takes a skip.